# how to write laravel sql query clauses on new line

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In codeigniter I used to write query on separate line using ';' separeted instead of '->' sign,
example:

```
$color = 'red';
$this->db->select('id, name');
if($color){
    $this->db->where('color', $color);
}
$query = $this->db->get('product');
```

Same thing I want in laravel. color where clause should be apply when I select color.

```
$query = DB::table('product')
if($color){
  ->whereColor($color)
}
->get();
```

But its showing error "syntax error, unexpected 'if'"
How do I write such query in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Method chaining returns the query object. So you can use your `$query` variable.

```
$query = DB::table('product');
if($color){
  $query->whereColor($color);
}
$query->get();
```

Don't forget to put a `;` on the end of each line still.

Answer (score 0):

Please, add where clause like  $query->where('color', '$color');

```
  $color = 'red';
    $query = DB::table('product');
    if($color){
      $query->where('color', '$color');
    }

    $rows = $query->get();
```

============
Another way is:

```
 $rows = Product::where_color('$color')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

u need chain, u cant use "->" operator without object:
try chain, using $query varabile, like this:

```
$query = DB::table('product'); // create instance
 if($color){
   $query->whereColor($color); // chain here
 }
 $query = $query->get(); // get result
```